# Search for array in array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, search, recursion

I've found a few questions about searching arrays but none seem to satisfy my needs.

Basically I'm importing a large set of data from a CSV. I have:

```
$categories = array(
  [4] => array([1] => root_category, [2] => child_category, [3] => another_child, [4] => last_category),
  [8] => array([5] => root_category, [6] => child_category, [7] => another_child, [8] => last_category),
  [12] => array([9] => root_category, [10] => child_category, [11] => another_child, [12] => last_category),
);

// Category to insert:

$insert_category = array([1] => root_category, [2] => child_category, [3] => another_child, [4] => last_category);
```

I need to see if `$insert_category` already exists in `$categories` and then I need to return the key (which is the end ID of the category hierarchy) of the `$categories` array that matches.

In the $categories I have around 7500 rows of categories, a foreach loop over the `$categories` foreach `$insert_category` is hitting the max execution time so I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this?

I'm currently using something like this:

```
  if(count($categories) > 0)
  {
    foreach($categories as $key => $category)
    {
      if(count(array_diff($insert_category, $category)) === 0)
      {
        return $key;
      }
    }
  }
```

Which is giving me "Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded".

Some of the functions I'm using:

```html
function get_category_parents($category_id, &$categories = array())
 {
  $db = new Database();

  $category_id = $db->prepareDBValue($category_id);

  $category = $this->get_category($category_id);

  // Append the category to the list
  $categories[] = $category;

  if($category->parentid !== '0')
  {
   // find its parent
   $SQL = "SELECT ID FROM categories WHERE ID = '$category->parentid'";

   $parentid = $db->getValue($SQL);

   if(is_numeric($parentid))
   {
    $this->get_category_parents($parentid, $categories);
   }
  }

  // No more parents, return the array
  return array_reverse($categories);
 }
```

```html
function category_options($categories) 
 {
  $categoryObj = new Productcategories();

  $category_options = $categoryObj->array_flatten($categories);

  foreach($category_options as $key => $category)
  {
   if(!array_key_exists('children', (array)$category))
   {
    $parents = $categoryObj->get_category_parents($category->id);

    $chain = array();

    foreach($parents as $k => $parent)
    {
     $chain[$parent->id] = $parent->slug;
    }

    $this->options[end($parents)->id] = $chain;
   }
  }

  return true;
 }
```

Comment: Try: `if(count($categories) > 0) {
  foreach($categories as $key => $category) {
   if($insert_category === $category)
    return $key;
  }
 }` Does this works for you?

Comment: Also how do you get the array into your php?

Comment: Hi Rizier123, cheers for the prompt response, basically I'm grabbing all categories that don't have any children and then running a function (get_category_parents($category_id)) to get the parents in the form of 

[id] => array('id' => 'root_category', 'id' => 'child', 'id' => 'etc');

Won't === check to see if the keys match to? the keys won't match as their the category ID's which need to be returned if the insert array values match one in the $categories array

Comment: I've added a couple of the functions I'm using, if that helps, thanks again!